# How to manage thread blocking and unblocking with asynchronous events?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous, autoresetevent

## Background

I am currently recreating functionality of something with a GUI that works in and, but through a terminal interface. So the error is not on the other end with the events triggering, because it works in original GUI form.

I run a task composed of subtasks on multiple machines.

I subscribe to events which trigger when progress is made and print out a descriptive message.
A message is to be printed out for each X subtasks for all Y machines.

Asynchronous multithreading operation then occurs.

I would like to print out a message for each subtask for each machine being resolved only once.

I track completion of the subtasks, and keep a 2D boolean array where rows is machines and columns subtasks.

## Problem

When debugging I can see that the event handler methods below are being entered. The print statement in numOfSubtasksFoundEventHandler is run, but before I reach to set the AutoReset event multiple BigTask events are triggered, blocked at the .WaitOne.

However despite the fact that numOfSubtasksFound.Set() is run later, nothing else is printed nor does the program finish execution. Nothing gets past the numOfSubtasksFound.WaitOne s.

If I take out the numOfSubtasksFound.WaitOne in the BigTaskHandler method I receive similar behavior but a few messages stating the BigTask completes and then the program stalls somewhere else.

What is the best way to manage the blocking and unblocking here or is there a small fix?

## Goal

**What I need is a way to block the operation of the subtask event handler method until numOfSubtasksFoundEventHandler has run once. I only need numOfSubTasksFoundEventHandler to run once only.**

Currently the subtask event handler is not being unblocked properly. The switch case code is never executed after numOfSubtasksFound.Set(); is run.

```
    //MAIN
    bool[] machinesDoneTasks = new bool[numOfMachines];
    bool[][] machinesDoneSubtasks = new bool[numOfMachines][];

    try
    {
        //thread/task blocking
        numOfSubtasksFound = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        AllSubTasksDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        AllBigTasksDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        //Subscribe to events to get number of subtasks and print useful information as tasks progress
        numOfSubtasksFoundEvent += numOfSubtasksFoundEventHandler;
        SubTaskProgEvent += SubTaskEventProgHandler; //prog stands for progress
        BigTaskProgEvent += BigTaskProgEventHandler;

        RunAllTasksOnAllMachines();//this will trigger the events above

        //Don't exit program until those descriptive messages have been printed
        numOfSubtasksFound.WaitOne();
        AllSubTasksDone.WaitOne();
        //SubTaskProgEvent -= SubTaskProgEventHandler;
        AllBigTasksDone.WaitOne();
        //BigTaskProgEvent -= BigTaskProgEventHandler;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //print exceptions
    }
    //END MAIN
```

Below is not necessarily the 1st event to be triggered.

```
internal void numOfSubtasksFoundEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get number of subtasks from args after checking for nulls, empty arrays

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubtasks; i++)
        machinesDoneSubtasks[i] = new bool[numOfSubtasks];

    Console.WriteLine("number of subtasks found");
    numOfSubtasksFoundEvent -= numOfSubtasksFoundEventHandler;//don't subscribe to event where we get this from anymore

    if (numOfSubtasksFound != null)
        numOfSubtasksFound.Set(); //stop blocking
}
```

Subtask events do not necessarily get processed before big task events.

```
internal void SubtaskEventProgHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //null, empty checks on args

    //Wait until we know how many subtasks there are and the 2D boolean array is fully built
    numOfSubtasksFound.WaitOne();

    switch (e.WhatHappened)
    {
        Case.TaskComplete:

            Console.Write(e.Machine + " is done subtask " + e.subTask);

            //logic to determine machine and subtask
            machinesDoneSubtasks[machine][Subtask] = true;

            if (AllSubTasksDone != null && machinesDoneSubtasks.OfType<bool>().All(x => x))
                AllSubTasksDone.Set(); //stop blocking when 2D array is all true

            break;
            //other cases, different prints, but same idea
    }    
}
```

BigTask progress events occur at the beginning middle and end of processing. I only print out the details of the Cases I want.

```
internal void BigTaskProgEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Wait until we know how many subtasks there are and the 2D boolean array is fully built before printing
    numOfSubtasksFound.WaitOne();

    //null, empty exception checks
    switch (e.WhatHappened)
    {
           Case.TaskComplete:

           Console.Write(e.Machine + " is done task " + e.subTask);

    //logic to determine machine
    machinesDoneTasks[machine] = true;

    if (AllBigTasksDone != null && machinesDoneTasks.All(x => x))
        AllBigTasksDone.Set();

    break;
    }
    //other cases, different prints, but same idea
}
```

Comment: The best way to manage asynchronous operations in .Net is using async/await. What is exactly your requirement? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you post the code for `RunAllTasksOnAllMachines`? Also, can you shorten down your question? We don't need lines like "Asynchronous multithreading shenaniegans ensue." And I haven't figured out what "through a non-gui interface." and "other end with the events triggering." means. You need to re-read what you have written and make sure it is understandable.

Comment: @RobertoBastianic have updated the description hope it's clearer. It's just as it is above, everything I haven't listed works fine. 

I will updated my question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: @Enigmativity RunAllTasksOnAllMachines code is irrelevant and works fine. It's just wrapper, reference and generated code, nothing of particular interest to see, sorry english is not my 1st language.

Comment: @despair - You're doing a lot of work to make this "work", but maybe there is a way to refactor your code to make this very simple. That's why I'm asking for `RunAllTasksOnAllMachines`. Could you please show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that after the 1st event was triggered, other subtask event handler event would call .WaitOne which would block. This could happen after the number of subtasks is discovered. The issue then was the .Set would only be called once, and it would never be unblocked.

So using a boolean flag to be set when the number of subtasks is discovered, and locking the sub task event handler was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

An example of async/await model.
A number of tasks run on each machine and compute a value.
When all tasks are done the values are displayed on the console.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = new DispatchTasksOnMachinesService(8, 3);
            service.DispatchTasks();
            Console.Read();
        }

        class DispatchTasksOnMachinesService
        {
            int numOfMachines;
            int tasksPerMachine;
            [ThreadStatic]
            private Random random = new Random();

            public DispatchTasksOnMachinesService(int numOfMachines, int tasksPerMachine)
            {
                this.numOfMachines = numOfMachines;
                this.tasksPerMachine = tasksPerMachine;
            }

            public async void DispatchTasks()
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<Guid, Machine, int>>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < this.numOfMachines; i++)
                {
                    var j = i;
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.tasksPerMachine; k++)
                    {
                        var task = Task.Run(() => Foo(Guid.NewGuid(), new Machine("machine" + j)));
                        tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                }

                var results = await Task.WhenAll<Tuple<Guid, Machine, int>>(tasks);
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task {result.Item1} on  {result.Item2} yielded result {result.Item3}");
                }
            }

            private Tuple<Guid, Machine, int> Foo(Guid taskId, Machine machine)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1,5)));
                Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} has completed on {machine}");
                return new Tuple<Guid, Machine, int>(taskId, machine, random.Next(500, 2000));
            }
        }

        class Machine
        {
            public string Name { get; private set; }

            public Machine(string name)
            {
                this.Name = name;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return this.Name;
            }
        }
```